# Yii2 - Convert the value of an attribute that will be displayed in the GridView

Tags: gridview, yii2

I would like to convert the value that will output on the GridView.

For example in the image of my table below. If the Account Type is 1, I would like it to output ASSETS on the table. If it is 2, then LIABILITIES. And if 3, then FUND BALANCE.

[image: MY GRID VIEW TABLE]
    Here is my GridView in `view`:

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'account_name',
            //'account_id',
            'account_code',
            [
            'attribute' =>'account_type',
            'value' => Accounts::selectAccountType($dataProvider->models, 'account_type'),
            ],
            'second_type',
            'third_type',
            'fourth_type',
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Here is the `selectAccountType()` function in my model:

```
    public function selectAccountType($provider, $columnName)
    {
    $account_type = '';
    foreach ($provider as $item) {
        if ($item[$columnName]==1)
            $account_type = 'Assets';
        if ($item[$columnName]==2)
            $account_type = 'Liabilities';
        if ($item[$columnName]==3)
            $account_type = 'Fund Balance';
        }
    return $account_type;
    }
```

What did I do wrong? How do I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an anonymous function switching on accont_type

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'account_name',
            //'account_id',
            'account_code',
            [
            'attribute' =>'account_type',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                switch $model->account_type{
                  case 1:
                   $ret = 'ASSETS';
                   break;
                  case 2:
                   $ret = 'LIABILITIES';
                   break;
                  case 3:
                   $ret = 'FUND BALANC';
                   break;
                  default :
                    $ret ='NOT SET';
                    break;
                  }
                  return $ret
              },
            ],
            'second_type',
            'third_type',
            'fourth_type',
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```